# What is wrong with this proof of $\operatorname{Cl}(X_\Sigma) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{r-n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, exact-sequence, toric-geometry

This question is a bit urgent, as I have written this in my Master's thesis and I have to submit it next week!

**Proposition:** Let $X_\Sigma$ be a toric variety without torus factors, meaning that the minimal generator of the rays $u_\rho$ generate the whole lattice $N$, then with $r=|\Sigma(1)|$ (the number of one-dimensional cones of the fan) we get the isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Cl}(X_\Sigma)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{r-n}
$$
*Proof.* We take the exact sequence from CLS ("Toric varieties" from Cox, Little, Schenck) Theorem 4.1.3 (p. 172) together with the remark directly above:
$$
0 \longrightarrow M\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n \longrightarrow \operatorname{Div}_{T_N}(X_\Sigma)\simeq \bigoplus_{\rho\in\Sigma(1)} \mathbb{Z} D_\rho\longrightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(X_\Sigma)\longrightarrow 0.
$$
This simplifies to the short exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{r} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(X_\Sigma)\longrightarrow 0
$$
and with the homomorphism theorem, i.e. for any homomorphism $f:G\to H$ we have $G/\ker f \simeq \operatorname{im}f$ which yields the claim. $\square$

I don't think this is true, as CLS (and other resources) add a finite group to the divisor class group. If $\Sigma$ contains an $n$-dimensional cone, I have found out that $\operatorname{Pic}(X_\Sigma)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{r-n}$, but only if $\Sigma$ is smooth, we have an equality with $\operatorname{Cl}(X_\Sigma)$.

Where is my logical error, or can someone provide a counterexample? This proof seems to be too simple that nobody else would already have found it.

Comment: The quotient depends on the details of the map. That is, the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^{r}$ by $\mathbb{Z}^{n} $ simply need not be $\mathbb{Z}^{r-n}$. A simple example is given by the case $n=r=1$ and the map "multiply by $2$".

Comment: Oh shit, you're right. Is there any criterion, how one can make sure that this can't happen?

Comment: So if I take the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^r$ by $\mathbb{Z}^n$ why am I guaranteed to get something of the form $\mathbb{Z}^{r-n} \times H$ for a finite group $H$ and not something completely different?

Comment: That's a special case of the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID (the words "Smith Normal Form" might ring a bell). As for criteria, smoothness is one criterion, but I suppose that's not satisfactory for some reason?

Comment: Thanks. Honestly I haven't heard of these words, maybe it was not too intelligent to go straight into the algebraic + convex geometry branch skipping the general Algebra lecture :D
I don't reeeeally need this isomorphism anywhere, but I don't want to write anything wrong in my thesis. So I don't have any specific conditions, that are allowed/not allowed.

Comment: You could also make this into an answer, I would like to give you an upvote, as I was really desperate about this topic and you saved my day!

Comment: If not, I will later write an answer, so that this question doesn't stay unanswered.

Comment: If I have time tonight then I'll find a decent toric example to actually illustrate the phenomenon. If not, then I encourage you to find one (either after you've submitted your thesis, or as a good example to include).

Comment: How exactly can one use the smoothness to transform the prime decomposition from $\mathbb{Z}^l\times H$ to $\mathbb{Z}^{r-n}$? I'm pretty sure I will not have time to include a good example before my submission, but I will give it a try (if you didn't already do it) afterwards.

Comment: Now you are really asking other questions, but I can direct you to  Propositio 4.2.6 of CLS on page 179 and its proof on the next page. Also, it is perhaps worth noting that "Smith normal form" gets a mention on page 173.

Comment: I saw the proof of 4.2.6 as well, but I thought there is maybe some direct proof for $\operatorname{Cl}$ only using smoothness without needing $\operatorname{Cl}\simeq\operatorname{Pic}$. Nevertheless, I added a corrected version in my thesis and everything should be fine now (I hope)